# Laplacian of cross product of two vectors

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose A and B are two vectors then what is

$\nabla^2 (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}$)

I tried finding it on the internet but no luck.

Comment: Actually it is vector laplacian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian

Comment: Laplacian can be applied even to a vector.

Comment: Yes, A & B are vector fields.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Laplacian can also be applied to a vector by calculating the Laplacian of each component. It is even used in Electromagnetics....

Answer (score 3):

Note that the cross-product satisfies Leibniz's formula in the form
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ({\bf A} \times {\bf B}) = \frac{\partial {\bf A}}{\partial x} \times {\bf B} + {\bf A} \times \frac{\partial {\bf B}}{\partial x}$$
and thus
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}  ({\bf A} \times {\bf B}) = \frac{\partial^2 {\bf A}}{\partial x^2} \times {\bf B} + 2 \frac{\partial {\bf A}}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial {\bf B}}{\partial x} +  {\bf A} \times \frac{\partial^2 {\bf B}}{\partial x^2}$$
Similarly for $y$ and $z$.  Add them to get $\nabla^2 ({\bf A} \times {\bf B})$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Actually I have already thought of that answer but I was hoping to get an answer in terms of  vectors, curl, grad, div and directional derivatives like the ones given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities.